# I'm getting an empty test directory after migrating the trunk from svn to git using svn2git

Tags: git, svn, svn2git

I'm in the middle of migrating a trunk from svn repo to git repo. I'm using svn2git tool for this migration. I have created a copy of trunk in another svn location and I have executed the following command for this.

```
svn2git http://url/to/repo/ --trunk trunk --nobranches --notags --authors /path/authors-transform.txt
```

I'm getting the following output in the log

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /[path]/.git/
Using higher level of URL: http://[url]/billing => http://[host].com
W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): Filesystem has no item: File not found: revision 100, path '/project/usc/billing/trunk'
W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn is just searching aggressively for old history.
This may take a while on large repositories
r25173 = 40bd30da875c492122bfc004e1049133607d4076 (refs/remotes/svn/trunk)
r25202 = d8c0f924c9379810a83af9422fad062efe4a221b (refs/remotes/svn/trunk)
r25279 = bb5d420179a00881f22aef800814485c09246aa3 (refs/remotes/svn/trunk)
r25460 = b16479d8e770af1f5838649a4b4f2e9b0edc9d19 (refs/remotes/svn/trunk)
r25468 = 06de0fc83de5d40375756fb2ad26789394feeb83 (refs/remotes/svn/trunk)
....
r145380 = 6ce54001e57e0048e51272168eecaa4f5867bae9 (refs/remotes/svn/trunk)
r145381 = 5a2b104c8b0adf4721e9b5abc5e49b45e9ec3930 (refs/remotes/svn/trunk)
Checked out HEAD:
  http://[url]/billing/trunk r145381
```

And I'm seeing only .git folder

Shouldn't the files in trunk from svn be copied here?

Comment: `git branch` to list branches and `git checkout master` (or `trunk`).

Comment: But I'm already on master branch

Comment: `git status`

`On branch master`
`nothing to commit, working directory clean`
`$ git branch`
`* master`

Comment: What do you think about this? I only have access to this project in the svn repo. Could it matter for this outcome? As far I can see I think svn2git cannot find the root path of the svn repo http://host.yyy.com. Please share your thoughts.
`Using higher level of URL: http://[url]/billing => http://[host].com
W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): Filesystem has no item: File not found: revision 100, path '/project/usc/billing/trunk'
W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn is just searching aggressively for old history.`

Comment: Seems it didn't find files.

Comment: Do you know any reason for this? No matter how I give the url, svn2git cannot find the files in the trunk

Comment: Nop. I have never used `svn2git`, only `git-svn`, and only on rather standard-structured repositories (trunk, branches, tags).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193468/discussion-between-umanga89-and-phd).